# Error while importing xray json format result using XRAY Cloud API {"error":"Test with key XX-XX not found."}

Tags: jira-xray

I am getting error {"error":"Test with key XX-XX not found."}, while uploading xray format json test result using xray cloud APICall
**XRAY Cloud End point:** https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/import/execution?testExecKey=DMY-71.

**Xray formatted Json:**

```
{
  "info" : {
    "summary" : "Execution of automated tests",
    "description" : "This execution is automatically created when importing execution results from an external source",
    "project" : "DMY",
    "version" : "v1.0",
    "revision" : "1234",
    "startDate" : "2022-07-25T11:47:35+01:00",
    "finishDate" : "2022-07-25T11:48:35+01:00",
    "testEnvironments": ["Chrome"]
  },
  "tests" : [
    {
      "testKey" : "DMY-67",
      "start" : "2022-07-25T11:47:35+01:00",
      "finish" : "2022-07-25T11:47:35+01:00",
      "status" : "PASSED"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can access TestKey in jira able to Update test case too.

Comment: Can you check your xary client ID and client secret? Have they been created for your user?

Comment: Yes xray client ID and client secret created for my user.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no much I can provide here as 1) all seems fine, if you have the mentioned permissions ... and 2) this requires some analysis from the support team; my recommendation is to reach out to them, so they can help out: https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2

Comment: Has this being solved?

Comment: Not yet I raised request for Jira support, waiting for there response